# What is the next run date of a new SQL Server Job?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, jobs, sql-agent-job

I created a new SQL Server job which will run once a year, it's currently enabled and configured to run on 1st day of new year.

In order to make sure configuration date is correct, I run this command:

```
sp_help_jobschedule @job_name = 'MyJobName'
```

It returns "next_run_date" and "next_run_time" as 0.

How can I see next_run_date and next_run_time of a new SQL Server job which never executed before?

Comment: My command returned the result later. The reason was "The sysjobschedules table refreshes every 20 minutes, which may affect the values returned by the sp_help_jobschedule stored procedure." Reference: msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188924(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: hmmmm, so what is the sql to ask this question?

Answer (score 5):

You can also view the next run datetime from Management Studio.
In your SQL Server agent you can find Job Activity Monitor (doublic click on it).

[image]

Then you will see the next run column

Comment: My command returned the result later. The reason was
"The sysjobschedules table refreshes every 20 minutes, which may affect the values returned by the sp_help_jobschedule stored procedure." 
Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188924(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at <kbd>[msdb.dbo.sysschedules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178644.aspx)</kbd> .The column freq_type would give the frequency of job..

1 = One time only

4 = Daily

8 = Weekly

16 = Monthly

32 = Monthly, relative to freq_interval

64 = Runs when the SQL Server Agent service starts

128 = Runs when the computer is idle

Comment: hmmmm, so what is the sql to ask this question?